# Url rewriting on a directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, directory, wp-rewrite

I've installed wordpress in a folder (mydomain.com/blog/) along with woo commerce as a plugin and i'd like the url for the shop to be mydomain.com/shop/, any ideas how I might achieve this?

I've already tried:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/shop/?$ /shop/
```

and

```
Alias "/shop/" "mydomain.com/blog/shop/"
```

but neither has worked. My site either throws a 500 error code or doesn't let me access my shop with mydomain.com/shop/

Comment: find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong: You want to access the shop on *example.com/shop/* which should internally redirect to *example.com/blog/shop/* because the shop is located in the */blog/* dir. Right?

This is tested with [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/):

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect /shop/ to /blog/shop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*) blog/$1
```

this `http://example.com/shop/` is redirected to this `http://example.com/blog/shop/`.